# Popup a shape in Excel Desired Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to popup a shape whenever double click on a cell and I have wrote a code but its not working for me.

All I want is that Whenever I double click on a cell between `Range("A1"A100000")` then shape will be popup otherwise it will be hidden.

My code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5000")) Is Nothing Then
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 4").Visible = True
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have been trying to popup a shape whenever DoubleClick on a cell and i have wrote a code but its not working for me.

You have to use `If Not Intersect` to check if user clicked on `A1:A5000`.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5000")) Is Nothing Then
        Shapes("Group 4").Visible = True
    Else
        Shapes("Group 4").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

> Thank you very much its working great but its not moving cell to cell. I mean when i click on cell A100 it remains still where it was before. – Mento 4 mins ago

That is because you are not moving the shape in the code. Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5000")) Is Nothing Then
        With Shapes("Group 4")
            .Top = Range("B" & Target.Row).Top
            .Left = Range("B" & Target.Row).Left
            .Visible = True
        End With
    Else
        Shapes("Group 4").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note**: If you do not want the cursor blinking when you double click in `A1:A5000`, then use `Cancel = True` in the first part of the `If`

Comment: Thank you very much its working great but its not moving cell to cell. I mean when i click on cell A100 it remains still where it was before.

Comment: Yes that is because you are not moving the shape in your code. So when you click on A100, you want to show the shape in B100?

Comment: Exactly i want this

Comment: I have updated the bove answer. You may have to refresh the page to see the edit.

Comment: Thank you very very much i have been searching for this for so long then finally posted it here. Thank you very much @Siddharth Rout